# How Can Copy from one Arraylist to another

Tags: java, android, copy

How Can Copy from one Arraylist to another like Below.
I have Arraylist of below class like

`List<A> aClass = ...; // has some data`

`List<B> bClass = ...; //empty`

```
//imports Class X
public class A {
    private String p;
    private String q;
    private<ClassX> x
}


//imports Class Y
public class B {
    private String p;
    private String q;
    private<ClassY> y
}

public class X {
    private String r;
    private String s;
}

 public Class Y {

     private String r;
     private String s;

}
```

How Can i Copy from
`bClass` to `aClass`;
Like below
//bClass=aClass;

Comment: You can't add instances of `A` to a `List<B>`. What do you want to be added to `bClass`?

Comment: but how to copy data..classes have the same fields

Comment: Copy what data? They are different types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop for that:

```
for(A a : aClass) {
    bClass.add(new B(a.getP(), a.getQ())); // creating new instance of B by passing params to its constructor.
}

public class A {
    private String p;
    private String q;
    
    public String getP() {
        return p;
    }

    public String getQ() {
        return q;
    }
}

public class B {
    private String p;
    private String q;

    public B(String p, String q) {
        this.p = p;
        this.q = q;
    }
}
```